# What algorithm assigns rank to a long list in the fewest amount of batches?

Tags: sorting, statistics, subset, ranking

It seems like nobody knows the answer to my questions. My question is about assigning rank to a list and not ranking a list.

Imagine I have a long list of X people (ex. 1,000) to invite to my party. In this list, I can have ties/indifference and also omissions. Additionally, I can only rate K (ex. 5) people at a time on a scale of 1-5 (with the mentioned ties and omissions).

The questions that nobody seems to be able to answer are:

- What 'type' of problem is this?
- What type/classes of solutions solve this problem?
- What is the best algorithm/way/method to select the groups of 5 to rate so that the fewest amount of 'batch rankings' is required?
- What is the Big(0) notation of this algorithm?
- Given N batch rankings, what is the error in my ordered list?
- Given N batch rankings, what is the error in the currently highest ranking P people?

I've done of research and it seems like the closest algorithm I can find is pairwise comparison. All of your sort/order/rank algorithms already have the rank known, and they try to find the way to order those lists in the fewest steps.

I'm unable to find anything about the step before that. How the ranks were given in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This kind of ranking problem is very typical in the field of operations research. But surprisingly, there is no tag [ranking] on https://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: The answer to this question gives useful links about ranking aggregation: [Algorithm to establish a global ranking given individual rankings](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96121/algorithm-to-establish-a-global-ranking-given-individual-rankings)